# Qt QLabel default text

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

My code is very simple:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
    label = new QLabel("");
    connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), label, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

I compiled it, and no error or warning.

But When I run it, The UI like this:

[image]

Why `QLabel`'s default text was `TextLabel`?

Comment: Try adding a space to the default text. `QLabel(" ")`.

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you want a label that is not visible?

Comment: Agree with @jrok. Why _would_ you want a label that isn't visible?

Comment: Are you sure that the QLineEdit and QLabel you are creating are actually the one's being displayed?  If you have used the QtCreator GUI to create your dialog, then you don't need to create your own QLineEdit and QLabel, they will be inside the "ui" object.

Comment: @jrok looks like he's playing with QTs slots and signals.  The connect call should make the text entered appear on the label.

Comment: I hope when the program run, the label is not visible. when I input some text in `lineEdit`, the `label` show what I typed.

Comment: Okay, It works well, when I make `.ui` file empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read some tutorials from Qt docs. You're mixing QtDesigner ui with manual widget creation. Your default text on label comes from your ui file. Also you don't need to create your labels/line edits when you use ui file. Just get them stright from ui class. So if you'll get your ui file back to normal, then you may do something like this:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), ui->label, SLOT(setText(QString)));
}
```

Also change text in your label with Qt Designer by doubleclick on it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because both your

```
 lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
 label = new QLabel("");
```

are different that the ones you created in your ui. You are defining two new widgets, while you should probably reference the previous ones:

```
 ui->lineEdit->clear();
 ui->label->clear();
 connect(ui->line....
 //etc...
```